# Let F field and let L be the set of all polynomials f(X) in F[X] satisfying the condition that f(-a) = -f(a) for all a in F. Is L a subspace of F[X]?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm thinking of proving like this
Let f(a), f(b) in L => -f(a), -f(b) are also in L

f(-(a+b)) = f(-a + (-b)) = f(-a) + f(-b) = -f(a) + - f(b) in L

f(-ca) = -f(ca) = -cf(a) in L

But I'm not sure if I am allowed to do this:
f(-a + (-b)) = f(-a) + f(-b), and -f(ca) = -cf(a)

Comment: $L$ is a set of polynomials so you have to show for $f, g\in L$ $f + g\in L$ and for $a\in K$ $af\in L$.

Comment: So let f(-a), g(-a) ∈ => f(-a) + g(-a) = -f(a) +(- g(a)) = - (f(a) + g(a)) ∈. Is it right?

Comment: $f(-a)$ is a value, not a vector, it cannot lie in $L$. What you write is nonsensical.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just starting to learn Linear and am kinda confused with the concept. So f, g are vectors but f(-a) is just a point?

Answer (score 1):

If $f,g \in L$ and $a\in F$ then

$(f+g)(-a) = f(-a)+g(-a) = -f(a)-g(a) = -(f+g)(a) $

So it is closed under addition.

Closure under scalar multiplication you should try to figure out for yourself, using a similar approach to above.

Answer (score -1):

HINT.- $f(-a)=-f(a)$ for all $a\in F$ is equivalent to
$$f(x)=a_1x+a_2x^3+a_3x^5+\cdots+a_nx^{2n-1}$$ then it is easy to show that
$\lambda, \mu\in L$ and $f,g\in F[x]$ implies
$(1)\space \lambda f(x)+\mu g(X)\in F[x]$ or, equivalently, $(2)\space\lambda f(x)+g(x)\in F[x]$ or $(3)\space f(x)+g(x)\in F[x]$ and $\lambda f(x)\in F[x]$.

Comment: -1 The equivalence is harder to show than the statement in the question and only holds for infinite fields anyway (consider the polynomial $x^{q+1} - x^2$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$).

Comment: Why harder? What it is required is just that the polynomial $f$ be an odd function. I don't like putting downvotes but I see that you do. Cheers.

Comment: Because to show this you have to at some point establish that if two polynomials agree as functions then they agree as polynomials, and as mentioned this requires that there be infinitely many arguments to evaluate them at. On the other hand showing the the sum of two odd functions is odd just needs plugging into definitions.